# Is there anyway to tell if a Stalker is after you?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, you can obtain a DeathMark by killing a boss in the game. When you have the DeathMark, the Stalker Mini-Boss has a chance to spawn and attack you. The Harvester ( a Stalker-like enemy) sends you a message when you get his mark (well, Alad V does). Does the Stalker send a message like the Harvester? If not, is there a way to know if you earned a DeathMark, or if you have one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** The Harvester and Stalker both have relatively similar spawns. Each one will give you a Death Mark and send a message accordingly, as well as flickering the lights and playing their respective soundtrack.

Just so you know, this is all covered on the Warframe Wikia pages as well. http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Harvester
http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Stalker

Comment: By "message" do you mean a letter (like when the Harvester is out for you) or the in-game NPC talk message.

Comment: @ShadowZorgon Not entirely sure what you mean by "letter" but I think that's it. It's the exact same for both of them.

Comment: When the harvester goes after you, Alad V will send you a piece of mail that says you are part of his project now.

Comment: The same will happen with the Stalker, with the message "Your actions have consequences..."

Answer (score 3):

As of Update 15: Archwing, your profile screen will now tell you if you have a mark active:

[image]